# Suspicious Process*User:www-data EXE:/usr/sbin/php5-fpm

Tags: logging, forensics

I have csf installed on Debian server which uses nginx+php5-fpm and see a lot of these

> lfd[23293]: *Suspicious Process* PID:16998 PPID:16122 User:www-data
>   Uptime:824 secs EXE:/usr/sbin/php5-fpm CMD:php-fpm: pool www
>   lfd[23293]: *Suspicious Process* PID:17053 PPID:16122 User:www-data
>   Uptime:822 secs EXE:/usr/sbin/php5-fpm CMD:php-fpm: pool www
>   lfd[23293]: *Suspicious Process* PID:17113 PPID:16122 User:www-data
>   Uptime:818 secs EXE:/usr/sbin/php5-fpm CMD:php-fpm: pool www
>   lfd[23293]: *Suspicious Process* PID:17114 PPID:16122 User:www-data
>   Uptime:818 secs EXE:/usr/sbin/php5-fpm CMD:php-fpm: pool www

in /var/log/lfd.log While the server load is strangely high (+100) and ldf frequently bounce top on cpu usage list. 
I am wondering whether this signals some attack vector and if so how to counter it?

Answer (score 1):

While your suspicion can be legitimately addressed on this site, the solution to your problem is more suited for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), or, better, [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Usually, this is nothing to worry about, nobody is attacking you. This is a typical [ConfigServer Security Firewall](http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html) LDF false-positive. With each connection, a new `php5-fpm` instance is spawned, that's why you're seeing so many entries.

To solve this, just add `exe:/usr/sbin/php5-fpm` to your `/etc/cfs/cfs.pignore`

.

Comment: Well, I wish I could be as certain as you. But the unusually high load indicates that the server is under attack, even though you might be right about the ldf showing false positive.

Comment: @alfish Then you're showing us the wrong logs.

Comment: What logs do you need to see Adnan?

Comment: If your web server is consuming the resources, then it is better to check the access logs. It could be D/DoS or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I traditionally add these lines to every /etc/csf/csf.pignore file of server I setup:

```
# sineld
exe:/usr/sbin/php5-fpm
exe:/usr/sbin/nginx
exe:/usr/sbin/mysqld
exe:/usr/bin/redis-server
exe:/sbin/rpcbind
exe:/usr/sbin/dnsmasq
exe:/sbin/rpc.statd
```